# form submit causing multiple requests to load same page

Tags: php, html

On an HTML form users fill out registration data and then submit it to a PHP page for processing of POST data. About 20% of the time, when the user clicks 'Submit', the POST data is empty. Some investigation using Fiddler shows this when it works properly:

```
58  200 HTTP    www.awebsite.com    /?page_id=337   22,433  no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0; Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT    text/html; charset=UTF-8    firefox:9116
```

When it breaks, I see this:

```
56  200 HTTP    www.awebsite.com    /?page_id=337   144 no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0; Expires: Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT       firefox:9116            
57  200 HTTP    www.awebsite.com    /?page_id=337   144 no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0; Expires: Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT       firefox:9116            
58  302 HTTP    www.awebsite.com    /?page_id=337   16,561  no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0; Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT    text/html; charset=UTF-8    firefox:9116            
59  200 HTTP    www.awebsite.com    /?page_id=445   19,989  no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0; Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT    text/html; charset=UTF-8    firefox:9116
```

It's like the submit is submitting the page three times.  BTW, the HTML and PHP pages are part of WordPress website...not sure if that's germane but wanted to include as much info as possible.

Any thoughts on what's happening? Am I guilty of event bubbling?  I will be glad to show the code if that would help, didn't want to clutter the place up if it's not necessary.

Edit in response to comments:
First thanks to FDinoff for doing the formatting...I'm learning as I go, hopefully this works. 8^)

In order:

> @3dgoo: I was careful to click submit once only, so I don't think that's the issue. Wish it was!
>
> @jereon: It's intermittent, what a PITA, but I can get it to happen by submitting the page four or five times...it'll happen.
>
> @Eduardo: yup, that's pretty much what I'm doing as you'll see in my reply to @meewoK.
>
> @meewoK: Your wish is my command sir! Here's the form tag in my HTML:

```
<form  class="contact_form" action="/?page_id=337" method="post" name="contact_form" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

and presuming `validateForm()` returns true, the POST data gets sent to a WordPress page that's built using PHP. That's the `page_id=337`.  Here is the top 20 lines or so of that file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: DisplaySummaryToApplicant.php
*/
?>

<?php
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
if (count($_POST) == 0 ) {
    header("location: http://www.awebsite.com/?page_id=445");
}
require('wp-load.php');
get_header("header_reg"); 
//echo '<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">'; 
require_once (dirname(__FILE__)."/dbLog.php");

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
```

When the code fails, the `$_POST` array is empty and the user gets redirected to a page annuciating the error.  That's the `page_id=445` line.

Thanks everyone, your ideas and suggestions will get me to thinking along the right line.

Comment: Is it possible the submit button is being pressed multiple times?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem yourself? The term `event bubbling` suggests ajax / javascript submissions, do you have both client- and server-side validation?

Comment: Probably you're doing something like this:

`<button type="submit" onclick="doSomething()">Submit</button>`

Comment: Would be good to see more code from the specific HTML code holding the form+javascript

Answer (score 0):

You may add in validation captcha for each your post.. So when it clicked more than once, it will generate a new captcha code and return it false.

Hope it helps !